# Prevent winapi from accumulating the key pressed

Tags: winapi, assembly

I am programming a WinApi in assembly language in which the program reacts to keypress, problem is, if the routine is not completed and the key is pressed in meantime again, it starts accumulate, which means once the routine gets finished, it goes again and again given the times user pressed the key while the routine was in progress.
Classic message loop:

```
.MessageLoop:
  invoke PeekMessage,Message,NULL,0,0,PM_REMOVE       
  test eax,eax                                        
  jz near .NoMess                                 

  cmp dword [Message + MSG.message],WM_QUIT         
  jz near .Finish                                     

  invoke TranslateMessage,Message                   
  invoke DispatchMessage,Message                     
  .NoMess:
 ; some code
jmp .MessageLoop
```

And handle for messages:

```
function WndProc,hWnd,wMsg,wParam,lParam
begin
 mov eax,dword [wMsg]          

  cmp eax,WM_DESTROY             
  je near .Destroy

  cmp eax,WM_CLOSE              
  je near .Destroy              

  cmp eax, WM_KEYDOWN                  
  je near .keyDown ; when key is pressed, then it is checked what key it is, meanwhile I need program to ignore all keypressed

  cmp eax, WM_PAINT
  je near .Paint

  invoke DefWindowProc,[hWnd],[wMsg],[wParam],[lParam]
  return eax
```

Let's say I have routine to handle `W` button, in proccess of the routine I want all other `W` keys to be ignored.

Comment: Why not add a routine that discards any unprocessed keypress events at the end of, or on return from, the operation?

Comment: @WeatherVane Thing is, how to recognize, that the handler hasn't been fully processed yet, when another keypress comes.

Comment: Err... six inch nail, set a flag?

Comment: If you show me a human that can press keys faster than the execution time of a `WM_KEYDOWN` message handler in asm takes, I might consider this a practical problem. For all practical purposes, this is a non-issue. Worse, it's an anti-pattern. If the user presses a key twice I'll assume that they meant to press that key twice.

Comment: @WeatherVane might be the solution

Comment: @IInspectable I am moving the player after pressing `W` so it takes a while to finish the routine if I dont want the palyer to move "instantly"

Comment: @Croolman not really - was facetious. You'll destroy keyboard type-ahead which is really annoying.

Comment: If you are performing animations on the input thread, you are doing it wrong. Why not move on to a high-level language (say, C) and work out the general architecture. A C compiler is likely to beat your hand-written assembly code, too. Intel's Pentium was probably the last x86 CPU, where hand-written assembly had a chance to beat a C compiler.

Comment: And coming at the problem from a gaming perspective, I don't understand the problem If I press W twice, I'd expect to move twice, one after another; the message model allows this to happen just fine. If I press and hold W, then I expect to move continuously while I hold the W key. Windows also does this: I'll get multiple `WM_KEYDOWN`s, which has the same effect. In the case of a held key, some bits in the LPARAM get set to indicate such; check the docs. What you *can't* do is redraw everything in your `WM_KEYDOWN` handler, if that's what you're trying to do...

Comment: (I'm probably not the best person to explain why you can't and/or why it doesn't really matter since I have very little experience with timing game graphics; someone else will have to.)

Comment: Why do `WM_DESTROY` and `WM_CLOSE` both jump to the same address?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Because they basically do the same the invoke function `PostQuitMessage`

Comment: @Croolman Typically, `WM_CLOSE` would call `DestroyWindow`. You only need one `PostQuitMessage`.

Comment: [And `PostQuitMessage` in `WM_DESTROY` is a bug waiting to happen.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110912-00/?p=9673/) Keep it in `WM_CLOSE` instead. Use `WM_DESTROY` to free resources.